# Parse Sonicwall log file with regex

Tags: regex, parsing, logging, firewall

Another regex question from me. I have a log file like this:

```
1 2014-04-24T12:10:25.661222+02:00 id=firewall sn=0017C514CD80 - - - sn=0017C514CD80 time="2014-04-24 12:02:22" fw=4.3.2.1 pri=6 c=1024 m=537 msg="Connection Closed" f=9 n=9506215 src=10.126.80.94:3995:X0 dst=1.2.3.4:80:X1 proto=tcp/http sent=2354 rcvd=1982
```

I want to split "src=10.126.80.94:3995:X0" in three parts. IP, port and interface. I've tried a lot myself, but i can't figure it out.

This regex match everything:

```
src=([^ ]*)
```

This would match only the IP:

```
src=([^:]*)([^:]*)
```

That's all i've got.

Can anybody give me a hint, how to match port and interface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close, just missing a `:` splitting your two capture groups of non-`:` characters.  I also added one more group for the interface, and it would be any non-whitespace characters (`\S` === `[^\r\n\t\f ]`):

```
src=([^:]*):([^:]*):(\S*)
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/fP7fL9)

---

If you can't use `\S*`, you can replace it with `[^ ]*` since we really only care about stopping once we get to the space after `X0`:

```
src=([^:]*):([^:]*):([^ ]*)
```

Comment: Rsyslog didn't accept "(\S*)", i used "[^\r\n\t\f]". This only got the "X" from the interface. My full expression looks like this now:
src=([^:]*):([^:]*):([^\r\n\t\f]{2}) ...and it works. Thank you.

Comment: @user3674270, the reason you only got `X` is because you removed the `*` which means 0+ repetitions.  However, if `\S` isn't supported you might as well just look at non-space characters.